# Total angular momentum of three spin-1/2 particle state calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-spin

I've come across a problem involving a system with three spin-1/2 particles in a given state, for which the total (spin) angular momentum can be calculated using the $\hat{S}^2$ operator in the representation
$$\hat{S}^2 = \hat{S}_-\hat{S}_+ + \hbar\hat{S}_z + \hat{S}^2_z$$
The three particles are in the state
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(-2|\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle\right)$$
I am seeing that the solution to this gives a total spin angular momentum of $1/2\hbar$, but working through the problem myself does not give me the same result. I can see that applying each operator to the state gives a value corresponding to $S(S+1)\hbar$ which should then give a value for $S$ but, for example, the worked solution I have gives the result of the $\hbar\hat{S}_z$ operator on the state to be $-1/2\hbar^2$, which is not what I'm seeing.

How do I operate the constituents of $\hat{S}^2$ on this state?

Comment: Which book are you using? For one, $S^2$ and $S_z$ don't operate on the system "nicely," and won't give the result $\hbar s(s+1)$. You can apply the total angular momentum operator after using the Clebsch–Gordan coefficients to decompose your coupled states. (or couple your decomposed states? I'm not sure how the wording goes.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider each of the states in the superposition. Each of them is an eigenvector of the collective operator
$$S_z = S_z^{(1)}\otimes 1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes S_z^{(2)}\otimes 1+ 1\otimes 1\otimes S_z^{(3)} $$
since they each have two spins down and one spin up. Thus, they have a net eigenvalue of spin $1/2$ down. 
Explicitly, for the third element (taking $\hbar = 1$), 
$$ S_z |\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle = \frac12|\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle + (-\frac12)|\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle + (-\frac12)|\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle = -\frac12 |\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\rangle.$$

Comment: That makes sense but does the factor (-2) at the first element not give a result of 0 overall? i.e. -2(-1/2) -1/2 -1/2 = 0

Comment: No, because each of those coefficients is multiplying a ket (in the case of the -2 it is the $|\uparrow \downarrow \downarrow\rangle$ ket. You then factor out the factor of 1/2 and see that the entire combination of vectors is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1/2, which tells you what the total $S_z$ is.